# What does it mean having Typescript Interface and Class in same file?

Tags: typescript

I am reading through the `@types/node` repo, and finding stuff like this:

```
declare module 'https' {
  import * as tls from 'node:tls';
  import * as http from 'node:http';
  
  interface Server extends http.Server {}

  class Server extends tls.Server {
      constructor(requestListener?: http.RequestListener);
      constructor(options: ServerOptions, requestListener?: http.RequestListener);
      addListener(event: string, listener: (...args: any[]) => void): this;
      // ...
  }
}
```

Or this:

```
declare module 'url' {
  // ...
  interface Url {
      auth: string | null;
      hash: string | null;
      host: string | null;
      hostname: string | null;
      href: string;
      path: string | null;
      pathname: string | null;
      protocol: string | null;
      search: string | null;
      slashes: boolean | null;
      port: string | null;
      query: string | null | ParsedUrlQuery;
  }
  class URL {
    static createObjectURL(blob: Blob): string;
    static revokeObjectURL(objectUrl: string): void;
    constructor(input: string, base?: string | URL);
    hash: string;
    host: string;
    hostname: string;
    // ...
  }
  // ...
}
```

Or:

```
declare module 'fs' {
  export interface Stats extends StatsBase<number> {}
  export class Stats {}
}
```

What does it mean when you define both a `class` and an `interface` in the same file/namespace? When does `URL` refer to the class, when does it refer to the interface, etc.? Is this standard practice? What is the differences/similarities between the interface and class in this context, how do they relate?

Comment: Note: `Url` and `URL` are different identifiers. Your `declare module 'url'` example doesn't fit with the others.

Comment: Op, gotchya thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Classes and interfaces are subject to merging if they have the same name. You can consult the [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html) for what kind of merging is allowed. Class interface merging will result in an instance type for the class that has the members of the interface added to the instance type of the class.

```
interface PersonInterfaceBase {
    fromBaseInterface: number;
}
interface Person extends PersonInterfaceBase {
    fromInterface: string
}

class Person {
    fromClass: string  = ""
}

let p = new Person();
// All are valid
p.fromBaseInterface
p.fromClass
p.fromInterface
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgArQM4HsQElzTxIBCcGKA3gLABQy9yMUWAtqefpLIhAFzIgAriwBG0ANy0AvrVBciKdFGwhkEAB6QQAEwxpMOToR7tKtBo2Ysj3JPwxgooAObTatBABsyepSuTUdAxMrADC3hgY9o4u9AC8yABEiW40tJ4QYMgADsgJIBAA7vrKOAAUAJSSNAD0NcgAgp6eyHBQKABucJ7A2rTZAHQhbGQQNgr9Q1bhPpPD4zzuNEA)

Using merging avoids having to redeclare the members of the interface in the class (but it also avoids their definition in the class and initialization checks on them).

In the case of `Url` and `URL` they are two different entities and have no relation.

Comment: Any idea *why* these would have been written separately? In particular, the Node.js `https` example seems really odd.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder  both `http.Server` and ` tls.Server` are classes, so you can't inherit them both. If it said `implements http.Server`  it would have to re-declare all members of `http.Server` in `Server` so this is just a way to avoid this.

Comment: So basically, forcing a bit of multi-inheritance (at the type level). :-)